# Travel to Ukraine

Tags: poland, ukraine

I will be in Warsaw for a few days and wondering about a side trip to Ukraine.

0. Is it safe? This is not my question, I am willing to take the risk
1. Is it reasonably easy?  Google Maps shows a bus and train route taking 14 hours but are the services really running?
2. Is it a reasonable thing to do at the moment?  Are tourists welcome as a sign of normality and an injection of foreign money?  Or are they a nuisance or disliked as gawkers?

I am a dual UK and Irish citizen.  I guess that either passport would be suitable.  However, I would be using my Irish one in Poland.

Obviously my second question is rather subjective but has anyone travelled to Lviv or Kyiv recently and can they report on their reception?

Comment: 0. As it's an active war zone: no. 1. Last I heard (though that's a while ago), it's surprisingly easy to get in by car, at least for journalist types. You'll probably be stopped a lot by the Ukrainian military, but if you seem harmless, you're probably allowed in. Public transit I don't know.

Comment: I’ve read that (at least until Russia restarted bombing Kyiv and Lviv recently, not sure if that changed since) trains run surprisingly well. However don’t forget that your regular travel insurance will nearly certainly not cover you. I believe you need a dedicated insurance before you can enter, and coverage is limited.

Comment: @jcaron I expected that regular travel insurance would not apply but thanks for reminding me that they might check for suitable insurance.

Comment: From last year (though I expect the situation is very similar): https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/178696/travel-in-western-ukraine-how-safe-unsafe-is-it/178747

Comment: Based on a report from a prominent travel vlogger, having Russian visas in your passport might be an issue.

Comment: @jcaron I think that I will need to resist the trip for the moment and hope for better times soon.

Comment: @SpehroPefhany None of those in either passport but, as I just said in another comment, I think that I need to resist the trip for the moment.

Comment: [Here's a trip report](https://liveandletsfly.com/warsaw-kyiv-express-train-review/) from February 23 by Matthew Clint - an American blogger. Seems doable. This is one post on a series describing his trip.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm from Kyiv.

1. My son traveled between Kyiv and Warsaw last year. Take a train from Warsaw to Chelm (from Polish railways app) and buy ticket from Chelm to Kyiv (from Ukrainian railway app). There are 3 trains per day on this route. It's a better way to travel than bus. I have listed more options to consider in the blog post here https://ukrainefrominside.wordpress.com/2023/03/13/%f0%9f%87%ba%f0%9f%87%a6-ukraine-nothing-flies-there-how-can-i-visit-as-of-2023/
2. Tourists are welcomed here. Even though there are less people visiting than before the Russian failed attack on Kyiv of 2022, it's not impossible these days to hear people speaking English in the city center. Local people are happy and excited.

Comment: Thank you.  That's very good to hear.