# Would traveling to Russia cause problems for future US border entries?

Tags: usa, russia

I want to visit for 2 weeks Russia to have a vacation there. I was wondering if traveling there would cause me any troubles with US visas such as F1.

I've read online that traveling to sanctioned countries would 100% make me flagged and can be a basis to reject any US visa or border entries.

Thanks.

Comment: Possibly a more immediate concern: Have you checked the travel advisories / alerts of your country of citizenship to check the risk level assessed for trips to Russia?

Comment: Russia is a country at war...you should be more concerned with problems getting out of the country rather than future entry in US

Comment: [Related question](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/175521/)

Comment: There is not (and has not been, in recent memory) any country such that merely travelling to it would cause you to be denied entry to the US for an indefinite amount of time in the future. There were some COVID travel bans (now expired) where you'd be unable to enter the US for 14 days after visiting certain countries.

Comment: My country is not currently sanctioning Russia, and relations have been relatively stable. I don't even require a visa to visit Russia, but thanks for the concern. I was mostly concerned with F1 visa process because I plan to study in the US soon, but my vacation plans in Russia seem to not cause any problems about the visa or entry. Thanks for the answers

Answer (score 9):

At this time having been in Russia or the Soviet Union is not a problem for entering the USA.

But having been in Iran was not a problem before Trump took office. Trump might come back and has already mentioned banning people who have been in more countries than his last list, who knows what he will do when/if he is re-elected.

Comment: Is the second paragraph necessary? We deal with answers here, not speculation. _If_ it were to happen in the future the answer could be updated...

Comment: Yes, it is necessary. It shows that rules can change and that OP might take a risk on future travel.

Comment: Though if you really want to go there, Trump seemed quite fond of Russia during his last term so I feel the chances of his doing this are fairly slim; someone else however could well do it.

Comment: Having been to Iran is not a big deal, it just means you need to get a B1/B2 visa instead of traveling on VWP. If you're a citizen of a VWP-eligible country it's a visa that's super easy to get, you barely need to show any documents and its valid for 10 years.