Best (safest) order of travel for Russia and the USA (short research trip)
I’m a European academic researcher in the humanities (philosophy, philology) and
I’m thinking of planning two short research trips (< 1 week) to consult rare manuscripts in the near future (maybe 2025).
One trip is to the Russian National Library in St. Petersburg (Russia), the other to libraries in NYC and Philadelphia (USA).
(So far I don't have an institution backing my book project, so I think I'd be travelling privately.)
Do you have suggestions about the best order in which I should visit the US and Russia? The order is up to me and my priority would be to travel safe.
In tense times, I worry that visiting the US could make it more difficult to enter Russia shortly after, or vice versa – drawing the wrong kind of attention from border authorities.
(I’ve never entered either country before, nor had a visa refused.)
If entry stamps on the passport play a role, then my current passport (from a EU country) is stamp-free. (Though I might use soon it for a trip to the UK.)
As a dual national of (another EU country), I could also request another passport from my other home, despite the non-trivial costs.
Please forgive me if the question is naive! I’m only used to travelling under Schengen rules.

Related:  Would traveling to Russia cause problems for future US border entries? Is it safe for a foreigner to travel to Russia these days?

Note that travel to Russia is significantly more complex since they invaded Ukraine, with no flights or trains between the EU and Russia. Payments are also very difficult. Note sure about visas. Also, make sure you don’t run afoul of sanctions (I don’t think there are any that would matter to you at this time, but it’s not like I know them all). Personally, I think ethics would dictate not travelling to Russia at this time.

Comments have been moved to chat; please do not continue the discussion here. Before posting a comment below this one, please review the purposes of comments. Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an answer, on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

Not exactly the same situation, but still: I travel between Russia and USA on a regular basis (I have both citizenships), no problem at all.

Go to the USA first. Assuming you qualify for ESTA/VWP, the US no longer stamps passports, so there will be zero evidence in your passport that you've been there. In contrast, Russian visas are paper stickers and entry/exit are stamped, so your visit will be obvious and may lead to questions at the US border.
That said, I don't think you have much to worry about either way.

As a bona fide academic studying rare manuscripts, you have an excellent reason to visit both.
Russia is not on the official US shit list of countries that disqualify you for VWP.
I don't think Russia really cares about travel to the US, which is good since you may be asked about travel history in your visa application.


You will be asked about travel history in your application (for the last 10 years, IIRC), but no, Russia won't care about you visiting the US. Only Ukraine might raise questions, but I know people who traveled after visiting Ukraine in 2022 with no problems.


Russian visas are paper stickers . This is not quite relevant for the OP, since he has an EU passport, and most EU citizens are now eligible for a Russian evisa, for which you won't get a vignette in your passport (but they will still stamp it)


@berdario That is quite important because if you need a paper visa the visa will usually be in your passport well before you travel as you need to apply for a visa beforehand.

Thanks a lot lambshaanxy, there's a bounty coming your way ASAP – and @berdario for the e-visa tip!

It doesn't matter
Russia doesn't care about you visiting the US. I know several people who are dual US-Russian citizens and still visit Russia from time to time. Never once did this cause them any problems. Likewise Americans can still get a Russian visa and visit the country. This was the case even at the peak of the Cold War, as tourism to Russia was possible since 1955.
Likewise the US doesn't care about visits to Russia. Visas are still being issued to Russian citizens, although they have to travel abroad to get one as American consulates in Russia are no longer able to issue visas due to the ongoing diplomatic war.
Who does the US care about? As per the VWP program page it's Cuba, North Korea, Iran, Iraq, Libya, Somalia, Sudan, Syria, Yemen. It's been two years since the start of the Russia-Ukraine war, so I think its somewhat safe to conclude that Russia won't be added to that list in the near future.

Related answer: https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/175521/is-it-safe-for-a-foreigner-to-travel-to-russia-these-days/175525#175525

Thanks for your excellent and helpful answer. It was a tough choice which one to accept, between @lambshaanxy’s and yours!
Both address my explicit question about the stamps, and offer similar advice. The discussion and comments made me reconsider the wisdom of travelling to Russia now – always in the spirit of safety – and I chose @lambshaanxy’s answer with its actionable advice go to the USA first. Thanks a lot! -- there's a bounty coming your way ASAP.

One important thing to consider is that due to the ongoing war and heavy sanctions on Russia from Western countries, there have been a number of recent incidents where foreign nationals traveling to Russia have been harassed, attacked, abused, arrested and even imprisoned, ostensibly for espionage. They do this so they can use them as bargaining chips for prisoner exchanges with the West.
In that light, it might be best to avoid visiting Russia AT ALL. I do not know what manuscripts are so important, but in my personal opinion it is unlikely that any manuscripts in St. Petersburg are worth the potential risk of spending months if not years languishing in uncertainty in a Russian prison.

You might want to check with your foreign affairs department and the US embassy rather than people on the internet. My country has a "do not travel" to Russia, which is the strongest possible warning

I think this is borderline "should be a comment instead" material (the OP did ask about safety, but their actual question was about order and not about whether they should go ...)

I think OP's question is a borderline "asking the wrong question". Whether OP should go to Russia is a serious question at the moment

It's true that "whether to go to Russia at all right now" is a serious question beyond my explicit query. I'm glad that I asked here (not just "on the internet", but in a community with a valuable pool of experience and reasonable voices), as initially, in my idealism, I hadn't considered the "whether" question at all.

I'm not saying it's not possible. My aunt went to China during the Cultural Revolution as part of an academic tour. But going to Russia at the moment would not be a normal trip. Also very few commercial flights are going to Russia - I think flights between Russia and Turkey are still happening

@teambob And Air Serbia flies from Belgrade to Russia

It absolutely matters
USA maintains a State Sponsors of Terrorism list. One of the major implications is that people who have travelled to a country included on the list are forever ineligible for visa-free entry into the United States.
This penalty is retroactive - USA introduced the ban in 2015, banning people who had entered certain countries after March 1, 2011 - 4 years before.
The decision to include a country can come out of the blue, as happened with Cuba in 2021.
These two nasty properties can make or break your trip.
Inclusion of Russia is being actively discussed and the obvious cutoff date is February 24th, 2022.
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/State_Sponsors_of_Terrorism_(U.S._list)#Russia
Safest bet is to enter U.S. first.

This is incorrect, I think. The restriction when first introduced was made retroactive for countries previously on the naughty list, but not for new additions. Cuba's addition to the list and exclusion from the VWP both date to 12 January 2021. Also, the resolution regarding Russia has gone nowhere in over two years, so it seems there isn't the political will to make it happen.

Predicting politics now is as safe as playing russian roulette with a Glock. Noone knows what is happening in Kremlin and what shit they will come out when the boat starts sinking. Something is about to happen (and nothing is a subset of something in this meaning) and all we can do is to accomodate to it. Nothing more, nothing less.
