# Is it dangerous to travel in Russia, as a dark-skinned Muslim?

Tags: trains, safety, russia, solo-travel, islam

Is it dangerous to travel in Russia, as a dark-skinned Muslim?

1. while travelling by train from St Petersburg to Vladivostok.
2. Skolkovo, Moscow Oblast
3. Sankt-Peterburg, Russia
4. Moscow, Russia

Robbery, racist attacks, forced feeding of pork and alcohol, and so on?

Explain why.

Comment: Do the answers to this question [Visiting Russia as an Arab. Am I going to be hassled?](http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/60866/visiting-russia-as-an-arab-am-i-going-to-be-hassled?rq=1) answer your question?

Comment: @user568458, let me see.

Comment: Also for the 'brown' part - [Is it safe for people of Indian descent to visit Russia?](http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/68636/is-it-safe-for-people-of-indian-descent-to-visit-russia?noredirect=1&lq=1)

Comment: @user568458, the second link is obviously useless. Indian people will always get privilege anywhere in the world while travelling because everyone knows that they are nonmuslims. But, I know some Indians were killed by racist attacks in Ukraine.

Comment: @user568458, ok. the first link is very useful for me. I am interested to know the travelling in train part.

Comment: I think you're over-estimating how much racists know (or care) about the world and different nationalities... For example I've heard of plenty of cases of racists attacking Sikhs while shouting anti-muslim slogans...

Comment: Note that between 5 and 14% of Russians are Muslim, depending on the survey, with more than a million Muslims in Moscow (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Islam_in_Russia). Many of these people (and many non-Muslims in Russia) are brown. So while I don't know what their experience is like, it may be that you stick out less than you expected.

Comment: @anonymous "Indian people will always get privilege anywhere in the world while travelling because everyone knows that they are nonmuslims"

What? 14% of India's population is Muslim.

Comment: @DeepSpace, Yes. 11.1% population the USA are Mexicans, so what? India is primarily known as a Hindu country.

Comment: The ultimate rejoinder to this type of enquiry is: "define danger". Please see the referenced canonical, thanks

Comment: @GayotFow, that was very clearly defined in the penultimate line of the question.

Comment: @GayotFow, I need to know about the train journey. If any drunk racist collateral gang in the train try to forcefully feed me any pork or alcohol or not.

Comment: I also don't think you need to be in Skolkovo. It's basically a half-abandoned construction site, and if anything interesting is there it's probably on the wrong side from rail station. Better go visit something from `Golden Ring`. Or walk around Yandex campus and Mail.Ru skyscrapers.

Comment: @alamar, Skoltech?

Comment: @anonymous your question is just hilarious, the world has changed mate, I am Muslim by the way.

Comment: @Ulkoma, I couldn't follow you. Can you please rephrase?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think that this question should be closed as, talking about russian radicals and racists, they aren't distinguishing people by the religion, and they barely know the difference between muslim and hindu (they main idea is `Russia is for Russians`, they even can't say what exactly `Russian`), so the referenced questions, in general, answer your question:

Moscow and Saint-Petersburg are two biggest cities in Russia, and staying in their center part is reasonably safe, if you do not enter some suspicious bars and do not talk to the suspicious people.

However, train to the Vladivostok and Skolkovo is different, as there you'll definitely attract the attention of locals, so, if you can, find a company to these trips. Robbery in trains isn't a rare thing, regardless your skin and religion, you just should avoid strangers. About the pork and alcohol, I don't think that it's a real danger. If you're in conflict, your health is in danger, not your soul.

Also, Ukraine and Russia are different countries, so you shouldn't use some cases from one country to make a decision about another (there are more aggressive radicals in the Ukraine than in Russia).

Comment: It's pretty obvious to us what `Russian` is.

Comment: @alamar Really? Could you please share?

Comment: Imagine the response you'll get somewhere in a Red US State if you'll go like `Who these "Americans" even are?` at a random dude.
I suppose it will be along the lines of "f-- you".
Not because they don't know who Americans are, mind you.

Comment: So, no answer. Ok, another question. My parents are from Kaliningrad and some small city near Ural. Grandparents are from Ukraine, Karelia, Amur oblast and Tatarstan. There are two religions in my family, Muslim and Orthodox Christianity. So, would I qualify as Russian? And how exactly can you decide it? And I really doubt that a random dude from a Red State is a radical and a racist.

Comment: `Liberties aren't given, they are taken.`
Do YOU qualify yourself as Russian? `Yes or No?`

Comment: It depends on what is Russian is for you. I think it's rather different than what is Russian is for me. Also, are you saying that everybody who claims himself a Russian, no matter what race or religion he is, is Russian? Then you're definitely not a radical and/or racist.

Comment: I think you are a `Soviet`, and not a `Russian` after thorough investigation. Of `new historical, social and international unity of people - Soviet people`.

Comment: Soviet aren't exist anymore. So do you think that Soviet should move out of Russia? And who and how will dyou cide, Soviet or Russian a person is?

Comment: Both questions are out of scope for this place.